# How to reposition or combine multiple images into a single image?

Tags: image, dictionary, merge, photoshop

I have around 600 png files that are tiled or grid maps of a big location. These maps are named with numbers they receive according to their location. The maps intersect each other around 50 pixels. How do i combine them to form a single big map? The images has same resolution and approximately same sizes. All the images are the part of big image. I have used photoshop's photomerge but that is time consuming for large number of images.

My main objective is to create a large sized map with undiminished quality.

Comment: How about providing 2-3 images so that we can see what you are talking about rather than expectiing us to guess?

Comment: I need to have at lease 10 reputation to post an image. Hope this link works. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVeJtMn4xNsYnVQemdwdFcwR1U